# Add-Type failure loading EPPlus.dll

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm trying to load `EPPlus.dll` .NET assembly, from the EPPlus CodePlex project, into PowerShell ISE version 4.0 on a Windows 7 Service Pack 1 computer, by using the `Add-Type` cmdlet with the `-Path` parameter. Pretty simple, right?

I'm receiving the following error:

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly 'file:///c:\path\to\epplus.dll' or one of its dependencies. Operation is not supported. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131515).

When I load the same .NET assembly using:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("c:\path\to\epplus.dll")
```

... it works just fine. Any ideas why I'd be getting the above error?

**Note**: I unblocked the files, after extracting them using the built-in Windows ZIP utility.

Comment: Profile the Add-Type command with procmon. Of that doesn't help, turn on assembly fusion binding.

Comment: I think there was something wrong on the other system that I was using. I tested this out on my Windows 8.1 laptop (recently built, and no GPOs) and it worked fine using `Add-Type`. Would require deeper research, but your ideas are good ...

Answer (score 1):

Run shell as administrator (elevated prompt)?